# Maximal Permutations of numbers with monotonic objective function

Tags: optimization, permutations

I felt confident in the validity of the following statement, but now that I've played with the proof more I'm starting to have a few minor doubts. Any thoughts?

Suppose you have two partitions of $(0,1)$ of the same length such that
$0<X_1<...<X_n<1$, and $0<Y_1<...<Y_n <1$
Now suppose you have a function
$F(x,y):\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that
$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x},\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}>0$ $\forall x,y \in(0,1)$.

Consider permutations $\rho,\sigma$ of $N\subset\mathbb{N}$ where $N=\{1,...,n\}$,
$\rho,\sigma:N\to N$ such that both of these permuations are 1-1.

Please, prove or disprove the following:
$\sum_{i=1}^{n}F(x_{\rho_i}, y_{\sigma_i})$ is maximized when
$x_{\rho_i}\leq x_{\rho_{i+1}}$, $y_{\sigma_i}\leq y_{\sigma_{i+1}}$ $\\$ $\forall i<n \in N$

Essentially, the claim is that the sum of the interactions between these two sets is maximized when they are ordered. I'm hoping that the condition of the positivity of the partial derivatives will be sufficient for this claim.

I tried a stab at a proof by contradiction:

Let's call $x'_i = x_{\rho_{i}}$, $y'_i = y_{\sigma_{i}}$, and suppose you've found $\rho,\sigma$ such that $x_{\rho_i}\leq x_{\rho_{i+1}}$, $y_{\sigma_i}\leq y_{\sigma_{i+1}}$ $\forall i<n \in N$. Suppose $\exists l,k\in N$ such that $x'_l\leq x'_k$ and $y'_l\leq y'_k$ but
$F(x'_k,y'_k) + F(x'_l,y'_l)< F(x'_k,y'_l) + F(x'_l,y'_k)$
$F(x'_k,y'_k) -  F(x'_l,y'_l)< F(x'_k,y'_l) + F(x'_l,y'_k) - 2F(x'_l,y'_l)$
$F(x'_k,y'_k) -  F(x'_l,y'_l)< (F(x'_k,y'_l) - F(x'_l,y'_l)) + (F(x'_l,y'_k) - F(x'_l,y'_l))$

and that's where I get stuck. I'm trying to imagine what kind of function might have this property, because I have a hard time pushing it past this point.

Comment: You should reduce your question to only what is needed. In this case the question has nothing to do with random variables.

Comment: @user21820 is that better?

Comment: Yup! I'm in the midst of typing out an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition on the partial derivatives is simply monotonicity if you don't require differentiability. In that case it is easy to find a counter-example:

Let $F(x,y) = x + y + \min(x+y,1)$.

Then $F(.3,.3) + F(.7,.7) = 1.2 + 2.4 = 3.6$

But $F(.3,.7) + F(.7,.3) = 2 + 2 = 4$

Now if we want a differentiable one, we just have to smooth this example at the sharp edge. That can be done by an existential proof, but we can give an explicit alternative:

Let $F(x,y) = 1-e^{-2(x+y)}$.

Then $F(.3,.3) + F(.7,.7) < .70 + .94 = 1.64$

But $F(.3,.7) + F(.7,.3) > .86 + .86 = 1.72$

Comment: Makes sense. I was just starting to think about $F(x,y) = (x+y)^2$. It appears to also have this property.

Comment: Hmm that square function doesn't seem to have this property. In fact there is a general condition that can guarantee what you were looking for, which involves the Jacobian and not just the partial derivatives. But it's not a necessary condition.

Comment: $(1/3)^2 + (2/3)^2 = 5/9 < 1 + 1$  
edit:
Nevermind, you're right. It should be 
$(2*(1/3))^2 + (2*(2/3))^2 = 20/9 > 2$

Comment: could you please provide the Jacobian condition? I'm familiar with the concept of Jacobian and other multivariate calculus topics.

Comment: @jameselmore: I seriously cannot remember what exactly it was. You can try searching for multi-variate Jensen's inequality or rearrangement inequality.